# Does Apache keep holding a key file open when mod_ssl is enabled?

Tags: apache

I was testing my httpd config on centOS-like OS, and found a "wired" error `AH02574: Init: Can't open server private key file` in one of the VirtualHost, while another one doesn't produce any error.

In my config file, same SSL cert is referred by both (two) virtual hosts, of course is the private key file also shared. The `httpd` fail to start with this config. When I dig into the log, I found one virtual host (`example.com`) config does not produce any error, while the other vhost (`sub.example.com`, at latter lines in the `ssl.conf`) can't read the key file. I suspect this is due to the file was opened by the programme already, and hence stays on hold preventing it to be opened again. If this is the case, how should I solve it? An simple solution comes to my mind was to duplicate the key file, but I doubt for any security risk.

To give a better idea, below is a sample config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  # ... some other config
  SSLCertificateFile    "/path/to/ssl.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/ssl.key"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName sub.example.com
  # ... some other config
  SSLCertificateFile    "/path/to/ssl.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/ssl.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per answer given by Jimmy, You can include sudo at the beginning of the command as below. I have also spent some 2 hours battling the same error but this helped me

```
sudo restorecon -RvF /etc/ssl/keyfile
```

After running the command, it should show as per image attached. Then you can restart the apache service
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uipI4.png

Answer (score 0):

Although with a different problem, but [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32633142/18991903) also resolves my problem!
Here is the solution provided by that answer:

```bash
restorecon -RvF /path/to/key_file
```